# Bounding Areas using Feature Collection values (RESOLVE Ecoregions 2017)

Tags: clip, string, boundaries, feature-collection

I'm pretty new to the Earth Engine and have been working through some of the tutorials to familiarize myself with it. I have very little code experience.

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a line of code that will reference a specific biome in the Resolve Ecoregions 2017 Feature Collection and use that biome to create a boundary. I can always just trace this boundary in the code editor, but I believe there is a way to reference it from the source material to improve accuracy of my boundary and also save time. My usual method of clipping any geometry is as follows:

```
var NameofClipVar = function(image) {
  return image.clip(GeometryName);
};
```

Where `GeometryName` is the name of any shapefile or geometry point drawn onto the map via and `NameofClipVar` is just whatever I need that variable to be named. I would then reference this during filtering of say Landsat imagery. What I would like to do is instead of referencing the geometry I reference the name of a biome and its subsequent bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my own answer... In this example, I clipped the Sierra Nevada forests Eco Region:

```
var ecoRegion = ee.FeatureCollection("RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017");

//Image Collection
var l8_Collection_SR = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');

// Define a single region
var singleRegion = ecoRegion.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ECO_NAME','Sierra Nevada forests'));


//Clipping a single region geometry
var clip_SierraNevadaForests = function(image) {
  return image.clip(singleRegion);
};
```

This creates the clipping var needed in the filtering process shown here:

```
//acquire imagery with desired filters
var SierraNevadaConifers = l8_Collection_SR
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2018,2020, 'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8, 'month'))
.filterBounds(singleRegion)
.map(clip_SierraNevadaForests)

.median();
```

This clipped the Landsat 8 imagery to the eco region along with the rest of my filtering parameters.